# no text tag(i.e. <p></p> or <h1></h1) is creating new line, all words with different tags are showing in the same line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

my html is -

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-8 col-12 mb-4 order-lg-1 order-2 text-center  mt-3">
        <div class="rightside w-100 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-item-center">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase">তামিম ইকবাল খান</h1>
        <p>MAGI MAGI MAGI</p>




        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12 mb-4 order-lg-2 order-1">
        <div class="leftside w-100 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-item-center">
          <img  src="images/CV.png" id="my" alt="Trulli" width="100%" height="900px">
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    </div>
    </section>
```

and my css for special h1 is -

```
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: "sofia";
   font-size:5vw;
   color:white;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
 }
```

I'm using bootstrap 4.0. But p tag isnt creating new line, rather it just goes in the same line as h1

Comment: You put those in the same row. That is why

Comment: try changing display to block instead of inline-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change your h1 styles:

```
 display: block;
   font-family: "sofia";
   font-size:5vw;
   color:white;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
 }
```